# Does Smoking Marijuana Turn Users Tongue Green?

Tags: law-enforcement

With the recent legalization of marijuana in many states, I have noticed, more and more, an old claim - that smoking marijuana makes users tongues turn **green**.

Is this true and if not, where did this tale come from?

Apparently, Law Enforcement Officers are checking the **tongues** of drivers looking for a **green tongue** as an indicator of marijuana use.

I can't find any Police Department that has a written policy on this but it seems to be prevalent throughout the United States. There are numerous criminal defenses that indicate that the officer used it as a basis for an arrest. Hopefully the fact that people are being arrested and jailed based on this is enough to make this a notable claim.

[Is a green tongue enough for a dui arrest](https://www.leyba-defense.com/is-a-green-tongue-enough-for-a-dui-arrest/)

[The Fallacy of the Green Tongue](https://www.ncdd.com/blog/577d2b851f1d75f63ac312a3/from-your-virtual-librarian-the-fallacy-of-the-green-tongue)

Comment: At the moment, this question gives two links, both of which refute the claim. One says where the tale comes from. The other provides references (via a court document). Can you explain why you aren't satisfied by these documents? What is left for us to answer?

Comment: (Also: If people are being arrest and jailed based on the claim, it would make it notable, but it would be better to have a link to show that is the case.

Comment: [One](http://q13fox.com/2013/02/26/man-arrested-for-suspected-pot-dui-over-color-of-his-tongue/), [Two](http://exclaim.ca/music/article/nass_dui_case_dismissed_as_arrest_footage_surfaces_online) alleged incidents of DUI arrest for 'green tongues.'

Comment: I don't have a reliable source, but this claim is just obviously ridiculous. Half my highschool would have had green tongues if this were the case, and I don't think I've ever even seen a green tongue before.